# Git installation

Tags: install, git

I have installed git onto my Mac OSX v10.7.5

I have downloaded and double clicked the installer package

I also ran the.sh for non-terminal programs

When I try to run commands for git in the terminal I just get an 'Illegal Instruction Message"

Any Help would be massively appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try compiling it from source.

1. Uninstall the binary.
2. Download git from [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.1.2.tar.gz)
3. Launch terminal
4. Cd to your downloads folder (don't do this if you are using wget)
5. Run `tar -xvf git-2.1.2.tar.gz`
6. Cd into that folder
7. `./configure; make; sudo make install`
8. If you'd like, remove that folder.

If you have any errors, please post them here.

Comment: Thank you ever so much!  Trying to start a flask project to teach to my high school class... This was really helpful!